# How to prevent Notification from clearing all activities in backstack

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an android app with GCM push notification ,in which  whenever the notification opens the page it clears all activities from backstack.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
long[] vibrate = {0, 100, 200, 300};
Uri notification = RingtoneManager
        .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
Bitmap largIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.small_icon_notification)
        .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setLargeIcon(largIcon)
        .setSound(notification)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg).      setSound(notification)
        .setStyle((new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()).bigText(msg)) .setAutoCancel(true);
mBuilder.setVibrate(vibrate);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: you've defined the parent in your Manifest  ? like this android:parentActivityName="MainActivity" if not add this line and test your code it will work fine

Comment: try removing autocancel

Answer (score 0):

To prevent Notification from clearing all activities in backstack, you must setup a Special Activity PendingIntent. A special Activity doesn't need a back stack. Use the manifest to set up the activity task options and create the PendingIntent by calling getActivity().

A PendingIntent specifies an action to take in the future. It lets you pass a future Intent to another application and allow that application to execute that Intent as if it had the same permissions as your application, whether or not your application is still around when the Intent is eventually invoked

By giving a PendingIntent to another application, you are granting it the right to perform the operation you have specified as if the other application was yourself (with the same permissions and identity).

The following code snippet demonstrates the process:

```
// Instantiate a Builder object.
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

// Creates an Intent for the Activity
Intent notifyIntent =
    new Intent(new ComponentName(this, ResultActivity.class));

// Sets the Activity to start in a new, empty task
notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

// Creates the PendingIntent
PendingIntent notifyIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notifyIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Puts the PendingIntent into the notification builder
builder.setContentIntent(notifyIntent);

// Notifications are issued by sending them to the
// NotificationManager system service.
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// Builds an anonymous Notification object from the builder, and
// passes it to the NotificationManager
mNotificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

Here's a useful link How to Setup a Special Activity PendingIntent:
http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

From

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

To

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(99,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Just change the requestCode and it works.